# jQuery Mobile - set scroll position of target page on changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm navigating from Page1 to Page2 in my jQuery Mobile site using the `$.mobile.changePage()` method.

I'd like to display Page2 at a specific scroll position.

Currently the only way I can get this to work is to call`$(window).scrollTop(this.scrollPosition)` 
from within the `pageshow` event for that page.

The problem is that when Page2 is displayed, it first shows the top of the page for about a second, then scrolls to the correct location.

I would like to be able to set the scroll position before the page is displayed, so the page is in the correct scroll position while the transition animation takes place. I've tried putting the scroll position code in the `pagebeforeshow`event but this doesn't work.

Is there a way I can achieve this easily?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Intro

Before I describe your available solutions you need to understand, this is not an error nor is there a perfect solution. The issue is that to animate the transition to another page the viewport has to be at the top of the page so that the current page and the page transitioning in are vertically lined-up.

If you were half-way down a long list on one page (say 1000px) and the page you are transferring to is only a few hundred pixels tall then the current page would animate off the screen properly but the new page would not be visible as it would be above the viewport.

There are 2 viable solutions:

### iScroll and its jQuery Mobile derivate iScrollview

iScroll homepage: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

iScrollview homepage: https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

iScroll is a javascript that can scroll content in a window within a web browser with very similar behaviour to native scrolling on mobile devices such as iPhone and Android. This means you can scroll a window within the browser using native-like scrollbars and physics.

That is also a solution for our current problem. Because of iScroll implementation pages will occupy 100% of page height, no matter how far listview is scrolled. This is also a reason why on return listview will still stay at a same position.

Of course in case you want to implement this solution you should pick iScrollview implementation. You would still be able to implement iScroll, but it would take you much more time.

### Silent scroll

Official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html

This jQuery Mobile functionality is also the same reason why we have this problem at the first place. Before a page transition is triggered original page is silently scrolled to the top.

In our case, when listview is selected, its position must be remembered (here you will find solutions of data/parameteres storing during the page transition, just search for the chapter: Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions) before page is changes. In that case, when we return to the previous page we could use pagebefpreshow event to silently scroll to the bottom before page is shown.

```
//scroll to Y 100px
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

And here's a working example of silent scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/2xfrM/

Unfortunately like in your example, this solution works only on pageshow. Because of jQM architecture it is only possible to do this during the pageshow event.

### More info

If you want to find out more about this topic take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-scroll-to-the-top-before-page-transition-in-jquery-mobile/)**, you will also find working examples.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've noticed that when you scroll down Page1, go to Page2 then click back in your browser, jQM automatically sets Page1's scroll position to what it was before, which is much faster than the way I'm doing it (there is no 1 second pause before scrolling). I thought there might be a way to adapt this when using `changePage()`, as currently using `$.mobile.silentScroll(100)` on `pageshow` takes too long.